# Foreign keys referring other foreign keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

In PostgreSQL I have a database, which I intend to make the following table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE canvas_user (
    id INTEGER,
    login_id VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    name_given VARCHAR(30),
    name_family VARCHAR(30),
    name_full VARCHAR(50),
    role canvas_role,
    last_login TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE problem (
    id SERIAL,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    author VARCHAR(50),
    path TEXT,
    compiler VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE assignment (
    id INTEGER,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    points_possible INTEGER NOT NULL,
    problem_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (problem_id) REFERENCES problem(id)
);

CREATE TABLE submission (
    num SERIAL,
    user_id INTEGER,
    assignment_id INTEGER,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    path TEXT,
    lti_info TEXT[],
    PRIMARY KEY(num, user_id, assignment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES canvas_user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (assignment_id) REFERENCES assignment(id)
);

CREATE TABLE correction (
    num INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER,
    assignment_id INTEGER,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    path TEXT,
    execution_time interval,
    PRIMARY KEY(num, user_id, assignment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (num) REFERENCES submission(num),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES submission(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (assignment_id) REFERENCES submission(assignment_id)
);
```

Everything works fine, except for the following error at the creation of the last table (correction):

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
>   referenced table "submission"

What I intend with the correction table is to have an unique correction for each submission but a submission can have (or not) a correction.

How can I solve this error? Is it a problem of design or just a table declaration mistake?

Comment: Add NOT NULL to user_id and assignment_id in table submission.(all elements of (composite) primary keys must be NOT NULLable)

Comment: @otorillas: Why don't you define a multi-column foreign key constraint on your  `num`, `user_id`, and `assignment_id` attributes in the [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statement for you `correction` table like so: `FOREIGN KEY(num, user_id, assignment_id) REFERENCES submission(num, user_id, assignment_id)`?
EDIT: Pardon, it seems that @ErwinBrandstetter already beat me to it with a more through answer. :)

Comment: Oops, failed to scroll and didn't see the correction table. NOT NULL is still needed, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foreign key constraint do not care whether referenced columns  reference another column themselves. But the referenced column(s) **must** be unique. That's what the error message tells you.

[FK constraints can be based on **multiple columns**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK). This should work:

```
FOREIGN KEY (num, user_id, assignment_id) REFERENCES submission
```

Replacing:

```
FOREIGN KEY (num) REFERENCES submission(num),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES submission(user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (assignment_id) REFERENCES submission(assignment_id)
```

The short form of the syntax (`REFERENCES submission`) is possible because referencing the primary key is the default.

Plus, you can simplify: make `submission.num` the single-column primary key, drop the redundant columns `user_id` and `assignment_id` from `correction` and reduce the FK constraint to just `(num)` - as discussed in [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867998/tim-child)'s answer.

With a multicolumn FK constraint, consider `NOT NULL` constraints on each of the referencing columns (as [joop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235885/joop) commented). Else, one or more null values in the referencing columns allow to escape the FK constraint with the default `MATCH SIMPLE` behavior. This may or may not be intended, typically it is ***not***.
Alternatively consider `MATCH FULL` for multicolumn fk constraints to only allow that if *all* referencing columns are null. See:

- [MATCH FULL vs MATCH SIMPLE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71508/3684)

Answer (score 3):

Make the foreign key from the correction table to the submission table a compound key that is unique.
Also, review the design of the submission table; num is a serial type and should be the unique primary key.  You can add a unique constraint to the columns num, user_id, and assignment_id

```
CREATE TABLE canvas_user (
    id INTEGER,
    login_id VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    name_given VARCHAR(30),
    name_family VARCHAR(30),
    name_full VARCHAR(50),
    role canvas_role,
    last_login TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE problem (
    id SERIAL,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    author VARCHAR(50),
    path TEXT,
    compiler VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE assignment (
    id INTEGER,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    points_possible INTEGER NOT NULL,
    problem_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (problem_id) REFERENCES problem(id)
);


CREATE TABLE submission (
    num SERIAL,
    user_id INTEGER,
    assignment_id INTEGER,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    path TEXT,
    lti_info TEXT[],
    PRIMARY KEY(num, user_id, assignment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES canvas_user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (assignment_id) REFERENCES assignment(id)
);


CREATE TABLE correction (
    num INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER,
    assignment_id INTEGER,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    path TEXT,
    execution_time interval,
    PRIMARY KEY(num, user_id, assignment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (num, user_id,assignment_id ) REFERENCES submission(num, user_id, assignment_id)

);
```

Comment: Good point concerning the primary key. But once `submission.num` is defined unique, `user_id` and `assignment_id` in `correction` are just redundant and should be removed altogether, reducing the fk to `(num)` alone.