# Set one column in a table as foreign key to two target tables

Tags: database, postgresql, reference, foreign-keys, cascade

I have 3 tables in PostgreSQL 9.6:

```
**table1 :** {id( primary key) ,account_id}
**users  :** {id( primary key)} INHERITS (common_table);
**channel:** {id( primary key)} INHERITS (common_table);
```

I want something like this:

*FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES (users(id) OR channel(id)) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE*

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. This is a known limitation of Postgres inheritance.

Read the [chapter Caveats in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS), which closes with the statement:

> There is no good workaround for this case.

Addressing your case exactly.

If you need an FK constraint enforcing referential integrity like this, you have to ditch inheritance. You could instead have `table1` as a "master" table holding the complete key space in its `id` column. And `users` as well as `channel` have their respective `id` as FK to `table1.id`.

Possibly add a `type` column to `table1`, a (redundant) `type` column in `users` and `channel` and use a multicolumn FK constraint, so that rows in `users` can only reference type "user" in `table1`, etc.

Your desired FK constraint could then just be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES table1(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Related:

- [How to have a foreign key pointing to two primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268886/how-to-have-a-foreign-key-pointing-to-two-primary-keys/42285952#42285952)
- [Foreign keys referring other foreign keys in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430409/foreign-keys-referring-other-foreign-keys-in-postgresql/25430588#25430588)