# How to enforce by constraint that a referenced row also has a given type

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, constraints

I have multiple tables B,C,D ... referencing one another table A.

Let's just look at A and B:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY
, TYPE enum_type
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  A_ID int REFERENCES A(ID)
);
```

Is it possible to check that A has always one specific TYPE when referenced by table B?

- every row in A referenced by table B has to have TYPE 'X'
- every row in A referenced by table C has to have TYPE 'Y'
- every row in A referenced by table D has to have TYPE 'Z'
- etc.

Is that possible somehow with constraints? Or do I have to use functions?
Or what is the best approach for that?

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. FK constraint

If you want to enforce referential integrity with FK constraints, you'll have to include the `type` in table `b` redundantly, add a (redundant) `UNIQUE` constraint on `a(id, type)` and make that a [**multicolumn FK constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) on `(a_id, type) REFERENCES a(id, type)`.

Related (with code):

- [Enforcing constraints “two tables away”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58972/3684)
- [Foreign keys referring other foreign keys in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430409/foreign-keys-referring-other-foreign-keys-in-postgresql/25430588#25430588)

#### 2. Partitioning

A less strict design could be built with [**table partitioning**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html). Have a master table `a` with list partitioning on partition key `type`. Thus you'd have a partition `a_x` with all type 'X', and a partition `a_y` with all type 'Y'. Then create FK constraints to the respective partition and you can be sure of the type.

I suggest ***list partitioning*** in Postgres 11 or later. Related (with code example for list partitioning):

- [Is there a way to automatically update a view based on daily created tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/225873/3684)

Note that you can't have a FK constraint to the *master* table. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-LIMITATIONS):

> foreign keys referencing partitioned tables are not supported.

The FK solution occupies more disk space due to a redundant column and a redundant index. With partitioning OTOH, depending on your version of Postgres and the partitioning method chosen, you have to deal with the [limitations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-LIMITATIONS) / [caveats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-INHERITANCE-CAVEATS) of that particular setup, though.

#### 3. Trigger

You posted another trigger-based solution, which does not occupy extra space nor complicate the relational design. But it's easier to break / circumvent. Not as bullet-proof as the FK solution. Either way, here is an improved version of your idea:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
, type enum_type NOT NULL  -- ! NOT NULL or adapt check in trigger
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX a_type_id_idx ON a(type, id);  -- ! see below

CREATE TABLE b (
  a_id int REFERENCES a(id)
);

CREATE FUNCTION type_check()  -- ! rewritten
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM a
      WHERE  a.id = NEW.a_id
      AND    a.type = TG_ARGV[0]) THEN
      -- do nothing, all good
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Type does not match table type!';
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_check_type_b
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON b
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION type_check('X');
```

The index on `a(type, id)` allows index-only scans for frequent lookups. Index columns in *this* order. Here's why:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

You checked with `IF var_type <> var_allowed_type`, but `a.type` wasn't defined `NOT NULL`. `NULL` would slip through.

Assignments are comparatively costly in PL/pgSQL. I simplified the function to make it *fast*. `IF EXISTS ...` should be substantially faster. Also avoids a potential mismatch with `NULL` by inverting the logic.

- [PostgreSQL IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299037/postgresql-if-statement/11299968#11299968)

#### 4. Abuse a `CHECK` constraint

Even faster, and more hacky, yet. Make it `NOT VALID` to be largely legit. See:

- [SQL constraint to check whether value doesn't exist in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855197/sql-constraint-to-check-whether-value-doesnt-exist-in-another-table/34856566#34856566)
- [How to avoid a cyclic dependency (circular reference) between 3 tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124019/3684)

Answer (score 1):

Erwins Option actually worked for me, but as I have many tables and multiple fields so I went for a different option cause of the overhead in the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY,   
    TYPE enum_type
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    A_ID int REFERENCES A(ID)
);

CREATE FUNCTION type_check() RETURNS trigger AS $type_check$
    DECLARE
    var_type enum_type;
    var_allowed_type enum_type;
BEGIN
    SELECT TYPE FROM A INTO var_type WHERE ID = NEW.A_ID;
    var_allowed_type :=  TG_ARGV[0];

    --Check that TYPE is the same as table
    IF var_type <> var_allowed_type THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'Type does not match table type';
    END IF;


    RETURN NEW;
END;  
$type_check$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_check_type_B
     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON B
     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE type_check('X');
```

Comment: A valid alternative if you don't need it to be bullet-proof. I have a couple of suggestions how to improve and added a version of this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add check constraint for x y condition