# Can you add a constraint to an SQL column that checks the value of an enum?

Tags: postgresql, enums, constraints, junction-table

I have a `users` table in my Postgres database with a `role` column that uses an enum. The user can either be a `CAPTAIN` or `PLAYER`.

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS USER_ROLE CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE USER_ROLE AS ENUM ('CAPTAIN', 'PLAYER');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" {
  id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  role USER_ROLE NOT NULL
);
```

I need to create a junction table, connecting *many* `CAPTAIN` users with *many* `PLAYER` users.

I can create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_user (
  user_captain_id INT,
  user_player_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT pk_user_user PRIMARY KEY (user_captain_id, user_player_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_captain FOREIGN KEY (user_captain_id) REFERENCES "user"(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_player FOREIGN KEY (user_player_id) REFERENCES "user"(id),
);
```

Is there any way to add a constraint so that `user_captain_id` has to be a user who has the `CAPTAIN` role and `user_player_id` has to be a user who has the `PLAYER` role?

Comment: I never heard of something like this. Sounds like a business rule that you need to validate on your apllication during insert

Comment: The only way I can see to do this is with a trigger function.

Comment: And what about updates? An update on "user", changing the "role", should that trigger a validation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `PostgreSQL` doesn't support direct table references in check constraints, I used a combination of a custom function (`check_user_role`) and triggers to ensure data integrity. The `check_user_role` function checks if a given user ID corresponds to the specified role (`CAPTAIN` or `PLAYER`). Then, two triggers (`trigger_check_captain_role` and `trigger_check_player_role`) are created on the user_user table. These triggers call the function before any insert or update operation to validate that `user_captain_id` is always associated with a `CAPTAIN` and `user_player_id` with a `PLAYER`. This approach will make sure that the junction table accurately reflects the relationships between users and their respective roles, maintaining the integrity and correctness of the role associations in your database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_user_role(user_id INT, role USER_ROLE)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE
  user_role USER_ROLE;
BEGIN
  SELECT role INTO user_role FROM "user" WHERE id = user_id;
  RETURN user_role = role;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then write a Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_check_captain_role()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NOT check_user_role(NEW.user_captain_id, 'CAPTAIN') THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'user_captain_id must have the CAPTAIN role';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_user_user_before_insert_or_update_captain
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON user_user
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trigger_check_captain_role();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_check_player_role()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NOT check_user_role(NEW.user_player_id, 'PLAYER') THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'user_player_id must have the PLAYER role';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_user_user_before_insert_or_update_player
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON user_user
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trigger_check_player_role();
```

Comment: I like this solution. I just combined the `trigger_check_captain_role()` and `trigger_check_player_role()` into a single `trigger_check_user_role()` function that contains both `IF` statements.

Comment: Ok if you like the answer please accept

Comment: 0. The first function doesn't need `LANGUAGE plgpsql` overhead. Rewriting it to plain `LANGUAGE sql` will speed it up. 1. It might be a good idea to define these as [`constraint triggers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#id-1.9.3.93.6). 2. It's simple and intuitive, it works. But compared to a [purely declarative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77803869/5298879) it's way slower, way less maintainable and it'll suffer from race conditions; at some point you'll find "impossible" entries just because things ran concurrently and executed in an unexpected order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **bullet-proof implementation** with multicolumn FK constraints:

```sql
CREATE TYPE user_role AS enum ('CAPTAIN', 'PLAYER');

CREATE TABLE users (
  id   int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, role user_role NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT users_id_role_uniq UNIQUE (id, role)  -- required for FKs
);

CREATE TABLE user_user (
  captain_id   int
, player_id    int
, captain_role user_role NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('CAPTAIN') STORED
, player_role  user_role NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('PLAYER') STORED
, CONSTRAINT pk_user_user PRIMARY KEY (captain_id, player_id)
, CONSTRAINT fk_captain FOREIGN KEY (captain_id, captain_role) REFERENCES users(id, role)
, CONSTRAINT fk_player  FOREIGN KEY (player_id, player_role)   REFERENCES users(id, role)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tUrBrCoB)

Downsides:

Redundant `UNIQUE` constraint `users_id_role_uniq` in table `users`.

Redundant columns `captain_role` and `player_role` in table `user_user`. Since those hold constant values, I made both out to be generated columns. So you don't have to worry about them, and you also cannot corrupt them. (Sadly, FK constraints do not allow constants instead of actual columns.)
About generated columns:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived / generated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-generated-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Related:

- [How to enforce by constraint that a referenced row also has a given type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464282/how-to-enforce-by-constraint-that-a-referenced-row-also-has-a-given-type/55464368#55464368)
- [Enforcing constraints "two tables away"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58972/3684)

Aside: I wouldn't create an `enum` for allowed roles, and just use a 1-byte `"char"` field with a `CHECK` constraint. Simpler, smaller, faster, and easier to adapt later on. See:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rTCBCpfT)

Comment: "*Aside: I wouldn't create an enum for allowed roles, and just use a 1-byte "char" field with a CHECK constraint. Simpler, smaller, faster, and easier to adapt later on.*" Could you expand on the value of this? Seems like you're saving a trivial 3 bytes per row, is that significantly faster? The cost is users having to know that 'C' is for 'Captain' and hope you don't need to add 'Coach' and 'Cheerleader'.

Comment: @Schwern: Actually, we are not even saving those 3 bytes in the simple example as that is eaten by alignment padding. (Some bytes might be saved in the real situation.) The main advantage is not to involve an enum. It's a pain to later add or remove allowed values. It's not significantly faster. But I would still prefer it. I'd rather not have to spell out 'CAPTAIN' every time to begin with. Nobody needs that for just two possible values.

Comment: @Schwern I'd argue `C` doesn't convey *much less* information than `Captain` - they are both more or less incomplete. In both cases I'd expect a dict/ref/info table that tells you more about the role ('of a ship', 'of breakfast cereal', min this, max that, fk to a role they report to), so it can also map the `'c'::"char"` to `'captain'::text`. What `enum` does is just the latter, mapping "lightweight" internal representation of a label to its full form, but since it doesn't let you add anything on top of that (except `comment on`), you still need to add that dict table to hold other stuff.